# How to Regex multiline text to specifics occurrences

Tags: regex

I have text file with big lines. Each "Reference" has your Data and any texts.
How I get all lines only "Reference CI-PERSONA"?

```
Date: 28/10/2017
Reference: CI-Auto
1. any text any text

2. any text any text

Date: 29/10/2017
Reference: CI-Persona
1. any text any text


Date: 29/10/2017
Reference: CI-Persona
1. any text any text

2. any text any text

Date: 29/10/2017
Reference: CI-Civil
1. any text any text

2. any text any text

3. any text any text

Date: 29/10/2017
Reference: CI-Persona
1. any text any text
```

The result expected is:

> ```
> Date: 29/10/2017
> Reference: CI-Persona
> 1. any text any text
>
>
> Date: 29/10/2017
> Reference: CI-Persona
> 1. any text any text
>
> 2. any text any text
>
> Date: 29/10/2017
> Reference: CI-Persona
> 1. any text any text
> ```

Can anyone help me, please? I am using C#.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your language / environment?

Comment: Hint: split on the date (`^Date:.+`), trim the resulting parts and check if it starts with `Reference: CI-Persona`, see a (`Python`) [**demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/3TBvOH)

Comment: Read line by line, use `StartsWith` to check the string at the start of the line and add a bit of a logic. No need to use regex here.

Answer (score 0):

Not great, but it works:

```
string pattern = @"Date:\s\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}(\n|\r|\r\n)Reference:.CI-Persona(?:(?!\s^Date).)+";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```